# FFMPEG: How to merge a video file (with its own audio) and an audio track (that should loop to fit the vido length)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, mp3

So, I have a video called `video.mp4`, and the video has its own audio track.
I also have an audio track called `background.mp3`, and I want it to loop for the duration of the video.

How do I merge `video.mp4` and `background.mp3` (looping to video length) so I can hear both video.mp4's audio, and the background audio in the output video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-stream_loop` and [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i background.mp3 -filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest" -c:v copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Comment: Wow, that works! Is there any way to make `background.mp3` 's volume be reduced?

Comment: @Corman One method is to add the [volume filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#volume): `-filter_complex "[1:a]volume=0.5[bg];[0:a][bg]amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest"`